# firebase codebase mixup

Tags: firebase, visual-studio-code, codebase

I ended up somehow to have 2 functions with 2 codebases, and I do not know now how to remove one of them.

So, when I use firebase deploy --project myelrondstats I get the bellow error:

Error: More than one codebase claims following functions:

projects/myelrondstats/locations/us-central1/functions/ClearCountField24h: enra,myelrondstats

projects/myelrondstats/locations/us-central1/functions/UpdateCountField24h: enra,myelrondstats

How do I remove myelronstats codebase from this 2 functions, that should be only assigned to the enra codebase ?

Comment: This is the top google result for this error. Anyone have a fix?